Can components of an eigenvector be deduced using linear algebra methods?
In the following equation
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix} \psi = E \psi$$
by inspection, there are a total of four eigenvector solutions
$$u_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, u_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
having eigenvalue $ E = 1$, and
$$u_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, u_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
having eigenvalue $ E = -1 $.
Since any linear combination of 2 solutions having the same eigenvalue will also be another eigenvector with unchanged eigenvalue, we might have
$$ u_5 := 3u_1 + 5u_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
which also is an eigenvector having the eigenvalue $E=1$.
Even after requiring normalization of each linear combination, there are still infinitely many eigenvectors $u_5, u_6, u_7...$ all having the eigenvalue $E=1$ around the unit circle

i.e. there will be a "phase angle" corresponding to each unit eigenvector which has the same eigenvalue $E=1$.
Is there a method for discovering this "phase angle" of an eigenvector (whose component values cannot be seen directly) using linear algebra techniques?

What do you mean by "whose component values cannot be seen directly"? If you don't know the components of the eigenvector then what do you know about it?

Are you asking, "Suppose I have a unit eigenvector in an eigenspace of dimension two or greater. Can I determine from that information alone its angle(s) with respect to a particular orthonormal eigenbasis?"

Since we have the whole plane of eigenvectors, an eigenvector may have an arbitrary phase unless it is subject to additional constraints. The question is missing details for what else is known about the eigenvector.

@A.Γ. thank you. As far as I understand, u1 is a "type 1 positive charge eigenvector", u2 is a "type 2 positive charge eigenvector", u3 is a "type 1 negative charge eigenvector" and u4 is a "type 2 negative charge eigenvector" (spin up/down electron/positron)... I don't suppose there are any other details/information we know about a stationary non-moving particle?

@AndrewD.Hwang I suppose the big picture question is, since given an arbitrary eigenvector laying there in front of us, the phase angle can be anything at all (and most probably not a nice 0, 90, 180 or 270 degree angle), is there any valid reason to assign special importance to the eigenvector [1,0,0,0] and [0,1,0,0]?

@QiaochuYuan we can see the eigenvalues, but the eigenvectors are abstract probabilities (so it cannot be seen)

@James: you are doing quantum mechanics (you should specify this) so the answer is that it depends on what observables you have available. What you can detect physically depends on the eigenvectors of your observables.

@QiaochuYuan thank you, I think I'm beginning to understand it... A body that has a fixed location and is stationary still have another degree of freedom: it can do rotational-like movement in place while keeping its position and stationary location. But now angular momentum in 3D space requires 3 variables $w_x, w_y, w_z$ to fully specify its direction and magnitude, and there seems only 2 variables left in the eigenvector to encode this 3 variables information, hmm..

BTW if you are doing quantum mechanics, the eigenspaces are 2-dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$, so the spaces of normalized eigenvectors are 3-spheres (unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^2$, not circles. And if you ignore phase (multiplication by $e^{i\phi}$) then you get the Bloch sphere

@arkeet thank you! Suppose $\psi$ is 4-component complex-valued Dirac wavefunction. Then there are 8 usable variables in total, of which 4 are used for describing the electron and the remaining 4 used for describing the positron. Then, which specific 4 properties of the electron are these 4 variables describing?

@arkeet Can the real and imaginary part of a single component be used to describe 2 separate properties, or are there evolution rules that guard against this... so that in effect there are only 2 independent properties left that can be described for angular momentum, and nature chose $\theta, \phi$ so $r$ is always set to a constant?
